# Javascript "Syntax error"/"Object Expected"/''style.cssText' is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what is wrong with this code. I keep getting the following error:

> “Syntax error”
>
> “Object Expected” : ''style.cssText' is null or not an object"

This is what I got:

```
function doSomething()
{

var textarea = document.getElementsByName("mcRemarkOld"); 
turnTextAreaIntoDiv(textarea);  
}
function turnTextAreaIntoDiv(elem)
{
    
    
    var div = document.createElement("div");     // Copy significant attributes, customize.     
    div.className = elem.className;     
    div.style.cssText = elem.style.cssText; <<<<<<---''style.cssText' is null or not an object    
    div.id = elem.id;     
    div.name = elem.name;  <<----SYNTAX ERROR HERE
    div.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML; //`<a>` turns in  &lt;a&gt;    
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(div, elem); 
    }



 </script>

   <body onload="javascript:doSomething()">


      <TEXTAREA class="textarea_readonly" readonly="readonly" name="mcRemarkOld" rows="7"  cols="100" scrolling="auto">        <c:forEach var="mcbean" items="${form.mcRemarks}">---  ${mcbean.auditable.createdBy.firstName} ${mcbean.auditable.createdBy.lastName}, <fmt:formatDate value="${mcbean.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />

  ${mcbean.remark} ---  <a href="show.view_hotparts_guidelines?id=${mcbean.id}">TEST!!!!!!</a>  

  </c:forEach></TEXTAREA><br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is an array of elements

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("mcRemarkOld");
```

try by using:

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("mcRemarkOld")[0];
```

or

```
var textarea = document.getElementByName("mcRemarkOld");
```

Comment: okay when I tried :var textarea = document.getElementsByName("mcRemarkOld")[0]; ....The whole screen just widened out

Comment: When i tried: var textarea = document.getElementByName("mcRemarkOld"); ...got object doenst support property or method

Comment: Of course it whitened out. That's what you are doing: converting empty textarea into a div. Third advice is erroneous.